# How to change header title in react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native

**I'm making simple application using react-native, and I am Using react-native-router-flux.
I want to change header component from 'chat' to 'Username' when i'm in nested screen. I tried several ways but I don't know where to put the header component code.**

**Code for TabBar**

```
<Router titleStyle={styles.navTitle} >
<Scene key="root">    
    <Scene title="Chat" initial key="root" tabBarPosition='top'  tabs tabBarStyle={{ top: 0, backgroundColor: '#ddd' }} tabBarIconContainerStyle={{ borderColor: '#000', borderWidth: 1}} initial>
        <Scene key="first" title="First" icon={TabIcon}>
            <Scene key="scarlet" component={BlueScreen} hideNavBar  initial />
        </Scene>
        <Scene key="second" title="Second" icon={TabIcon}>
            <Scene key="scarlet2" component={GrayScreen} hideNavBar  initial />
        </Scene>
        <Scene key="third" title="Third" icon={TabIcon}>
            <Scene key="scarlet3" component={ScarletScreen} hideNavBar  initial />
            <Scene key="root" component={SecondScene} hideNavBar title="Username"  />
        </Scene>
    </Scene>
</Scene>
```

**when I'm in SecondScene I want my header change from Chat to Username**

Answer (score 2):

You can add this code in the Component where you switch the tab and want `username` as header.

`Actions.refresh({ title: 'Username' })`.

you can add this line of code as per your Apps flow.
If you are switching to `chat` you can add

`Actions.refresh({ title: 'chat' })`.

Hope it helps !

Comment: hiii abhinandan  i want to change title of my root header and i also hide all of my tabs header Hope you understand

Answer (score 2):

You can change navigation title anytime. For your use when you got the username just run the following code.

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
    title: "YOUR_USER_NAME",
});
```

If you get the user name when navigating to current scene it's better you change the title in componentWillMount.

```
componentWillMount() {
   this.props.navigation.setParams({
        title: "YOUR_USER_NAME",
   });
}
```